# Multiple input forms with same xaml file and different DataContexts

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, mvvm-light

I am developing a WinRT app using XAML and MVVM Light. This app is meant to make it easier to do data collection while the users are out in the field. I have a section of my app where users will need to enter in a bunch of information about several different items. These items are defined as classes that inherit from a `GenericAsset` class. The `GenericAsset` has fields such as this:

```
public class GenericAsset
{
    public string AssetId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

And the sub classes look something like this:

```
public class SubAsset1 : GenericAsset
{
    public string RecordNumber { get; set; }
    public int SizeDiameter { get; set; }
    public string MaterialType { get; set; }
}

public class SubAsset2 : GenericAsset
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public string PlanRef { get; set; }
    public string InteriorMaterial { get; set; }
}
```

Currently I have 15 SubAssets (and will have many more in the future) and I am looking for a way to create one data entry view/viewmodel (if possible) so that I don't have to create a separate view for each asset. Also, if I can get the generic view/viewmodel working, how would I go about loading in the custom data entry controls (the inputs specific to each sub asset) while maintaining the proper two-way data binding to the appropriate sub asset?

Comment: Well, if you don't want to make separate views or DataTamplates for each entity then I guess you'll have to create view programmatically with controls added based on field type.

Comment: Personally I'd compose my view from two parts: one part covering the generic properties and then another part specific for the subasset type. In this way I'd have complete control of the user experience when entering data and could (for example) decided that UI for `InteriorMaterial` property of `SubAsset2` should be entered with a `DropDown`, whereas `PlanRef` needs specific RegEx to validate  it. Just because they are both `string` doesn't automatically mean they should just use a `TextBox` for entering data.

Comment: Currently I do have the view sectioned off into two parts. I have a Generic Asset Info section and a Specific Asset Info section. I'm trying to figure out the best way to have one view that has all the generic fields, then dynamically loads the appropriate specific fields, such as from an external XAML file or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a `DataTemplateSelector`. Create a different `DataTemplate` for each `SubAsset`. Then, display the `Asset` via a `ContentControl` (or `ListView` in the case of multiple of them). Both of them have a slot for a `DataTemplateSelector` (`ContentTemplateSelector` and `ItemTemplateSelector`, respectively). If there are parts that are similar between them, you can actually compose one `DataTemplate` with another by using an inner `ContentControl` pointing to the target `DataTemplate` (that you wish to compose).

In order to add your `DataTemplate`s from different `ResourceDictionaries`, when you create your `DataTemplateSelector`, create a property for each `DataTemplate` that you wish to have.

Your selector may look something like this:

```
public class AssetDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate SubAsset1DataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate SubAsset2DataTemplate { get; set; }
    ...

    // Data Template Selection Code
    ...
}
```

Then in a ResourceDictionary (such as Generic.xaml), when you declare your `AssetDataTemplateSelector`, just refer to all of the other `DataTemplates` as `StaticResource`s.

```
<!-- This assumes that AssetDataTemplateSelector has been declared in a namespace 
     defined in the root of the ResourceDictionary as 'converters'. -->
<!-- It also assumes that you have created DataTemplates with the names 
     SubAssetXDataTemplate either in the same or other ResourceDictionaries 
     which are accessible from this one. -->
<converters:AssetDataTemplateSelector x:Key="AssetDataTemplateSelector"
                                      SubAsset1DataTemplate="{StaticResource SubAsset1DataTemplate}"
                                      SubAsset2DataTemplate="{StaticResource SubAsset2DataTemplate}"
                                      ...
                                      />
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give that a try. Also, how would I use the `ContentTemplateSelector` if I have all my `DataTemplate`s in separate `ResourceDictionary` files?